# JavaScript doesn't work after ajax loading (using table)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a table automatically generated by database using php with four rows ... the last row (4) has a button to trigger the function below... it repeats for every line.

after i click the button...the script sends a request to update database to switch the status "pendent" to "canceled".

at this point everything is okay... BUT...when i refresh the div with the table"$( '#lista' ).load(location.href + ' #lista > *' );"

the script doesnt work a second time after the loading. ( the div update is okay but only works a once)

i need the script working after the first refresh... everytime i clicked in the row button...

i think that may be a incompatibility of ajax request and javascript.

i really appreciate if you can help me.
thank you all.

```
<script>

var index, table = document.getElementById('table');
            for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
            {
                table.rows[i].cells[4].onclick = function()
                { //inicio da função
                    var c = confirm('Você quer cancelar essa aula?');
                    if(c === true)
                    {//inicio confirmador
                      var table = document.getElementById('table');
                        index = this.parentElement.rowIndex;
                        value_index_id= table.rows[index].cells[0].innerHTML;
                        var id = value_index_id;
                        $.ajax({
                  type: 'GET',
                  url: 'cancelar_aulas.php',
                  data: {id_geral:id},
                  success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    $( '#lista' ).load(location.href + ' #lista > *' );

                  }
              })

                    } //fim do confirmador

                    //validador
                    //console.log(index);
                    //console.log (value_index_id);
                    console.log(id);

                };//fim da função

            }
</script>";
```

Comment: You get the table length at the beginning (presumably on page load) but then you don't update it when you get new data. I bet the onclick event handler simply isn't being attached to the new rows.

Comment: no... it does not trigger anymore

Comment: if i dont load the div .... just refresh all page... works well... but i need something dynamic ... this code works... but if i dont refresh ... i cant do it again

Comment: i dont have a clue... my guess is i have to use ...jquery live() or delegate() ... i dont know how to do this ...

Comment: Likely you're not attaching the listener on new elements. You need to look at delegated events if this is the case. Basically instead of listening on the element itself, you listen on a container for events occuring on elements inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only attaching the onclick event handler to the table when your page loads. That's why it only works on the first click. When you add new data to the table, you need to do something to add the onclick event to the new rows.

There's a few different ways to do this:

- jQuery can attach events to dynamically created elements like so:

  ```
  $("table").on("click", "table tr", function() {
      // Note that this event would fire for ALL rows, 
      // but it will automatically attach this event to new rows
      // that are added after page load
      // This would work, you just would have to check if the clicked
      // row is one of the last 4.
  }
  ```
- Create your own function to attach the event, and you'll run that function every time you add new rows. Something like:

  ```
  function AttachClick() {
      let table = document.getElementById("table");
      let position = table.rows.length;
      while (position > table.rows.length - 4) {
          table.rows[position].addEventListener("click", function() {
              // Do your on click here
              // On success, you would fire this "AttachClick()" function
          }
          position--;
      }
  }
  ```

Notice the `while` loop starting from the end of the table instead of the start. If you had a table with a lot of rows it could be faster to iterate starting at the end (since those are the only rows you care about).

Comment: the function "this.parentElement.rowIndex" detects automatically and get the information i need... but after the load... onclick just stop working and  it doesnt trigger the function anymore ... i dont create new rows ... just re-loaded with the new information  ... its like the script are not detecting the element anymore... i have to reaload the script?

Comment: i tested without "$( '#lista' ).load(location.href + ' #lista > *' );" ... works normally and all the rows trigger the function... but doesnt refresh the table.... when i refresh the page all the rows i clicked change and update...

when i use $( '#lista' ).load(location.href + ' #lista > *' ); ... the function works only in the first attempt

Comment: The problem and solution should still be the same. When you load the new data into the table, it's probably destroying the existing rows and recreating them. Meaning that the event handler is lost. You can check this is the developer console (see if the rows have an event on them after you load the data). You'll still need to reattach the event handler after loading in new data.